# Trigonometric function, with calculus integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $\int{\sin(x) \sec^3(x)\, dx}$

So can someone please show me how to do this question. I am very curious as to how its done. FYI this is not a Homework Question.THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the integral is

$$\int dx \, \sin{x} \sec^3{x}$$

then this is equivalent to

$$\int dx \tan{x} \, \sec^2{x} = \int d(\tan{x}) \tan{x} = \frac12 \tan^2{x} + C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\sin x\sec^3x\,dx=-\int (\cos x)'\cos^{-3}x\,dx=\frac{\cos^{-2}x}2+C=\frac12\sec^2x+C$$

Comment: For a quick second, I got really worried and wondered what was wrong with  my answer.  Apparently, I should wake up.

Comment: Hehe...for a second I also thought we arrived to *really* different solutions....;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\sin x \sec^3 x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x} = \frac {\sin x}{\cos x} \cdot \frac 1{\cos^2 x} = \tan x\sec^2 x$$
So, we can write

$$\int \sin x \sec^3 x \,dx\quad = \quad \int \tan x \,\sec^2 x \,dx $$

$$u = \tan x \quad \implies\quad  du = \sec^2 x\, dx$$

$$\int u \, du = \frac 12u^2 = \frac 12 \tan^2 x$$

**ADDED:** 
If the integrand is actually $\color{blue}{ \sin x \cos \left(x^3\right)}$, then please note that this is not an elementary integral: there is no result to be found with standard (elementary) mathematical functions.